# Dangerous glitch or superhack?

Tags: apt, ram

Okay, so I need to admit that I'm not the greatest with computers. Which is why I need to ask if my system is fine or not after this.

So I decided to get an old project (a piano teaching tool, pianobooster, last updated 2011) when attempting to build it from source code I see that the instructions refer to a bunch of packages that i should have installed to cmake effectively. I go 'okay, let's just go ahead and input "sudo apt install ____" into terminal for all of them, if it's malicious then It's probably not in the default repository and if it's already installed I'll just get a slap on the wrist(yes I know. I should have "sudo apt search _____" first).'

So i do this for a thing called "libqt4-dev" which without warning or anything soft rebooted my computer, when checking my system monitor immediately I notice there's a file at the very top; called "ThreadPoolSingl" I go 'hm, that wasn't there before' and kill it. Suddenly i have ~400mb more free ram than usual.

What just happened?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. I'm sorry your question is _really_ lacking. What proof have you that `libqt4-dev` caused a reboot? Have you consulted the log files in `/var/log`? Was this interactively or remotely (e.g. via SSH)?

Answer (score 3):

You do not really need to compile PianoBuster by your own.

It is already in [the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=pianobooster). Install it as simple as:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install pianobooster
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's unlikely that `libqt4-dev` did something untoward to your computer -- while Qt4 per se is surely outdated, many many people used this package and (speaking for me particularly) didn't observe anything bad. Did you find something in the system logs that could explain the reboot?

For the **ThreadPoolSingl**, a casual search shows it is connected to (or a part of) Chromium. No surprise it can use hundreds of MB.